# Parsing a message with sscanf in c++

Tags: c++, scanf, stack-corruption

I am trying to parse the following "incoming_message" to different variables and the code works perfectly until the function ends. Then I get the following error:
**"Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'network_number' was corrupted."**

This is the code where I am getting the error:

```
char* incoming_message = "\r\n+COPS: (2,\"MOVISTAR\",,\"12345\"),(1,\"AMENA\",,\"12346\"),(1,\"E AIRTEL\",,\"12347\"),,(0-4),(0,2)\r\n";
int stat;
char network_name[16];
char network_number[6];
char processed_message[128];
const char* pch_msg = "%d, %[^,],, %[^')']";

// I introduce spaces to remove the inverted commas
for(int i=2; i < strlen(incoming_message); i++)
{
   if (incoming_message [i] == '"')
   {
      processed_message[i] = ' ';
   }
   else
   {
      processed_message[i] = incoming_message [i];
   }
}

for(int i=2; (incoming_message[i]!='\r') || i < strlen(incoming_message); i++)
{
   if(incoming_message[i] == '(')
   {
      i++;
      int const sscanf_res = sscanf(&processed_message[i], pch_msg, &stat, &network_name, &network_number);
      if (sscanf_res != 3)
      {
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

}

Does somebody have any idea why I am getting this error? Is there any other way to do it more simple?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The string `"\"12345\""` is *seven* characters long (two double-quotes plus five digits). How are you going to fit that *plus* the terminator (making it eight characters) in a six-character array?

Comment: On a slightly related note, remember that arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element, which is different from a pointer to an array. When you pass an array of characters to any `scanf` function you pass it as it is, and let it decay to a pointer by the compiler. Passing e.g. `&network_name` is *not* the same (semantically). So please drop the address-of operators for the strings in your `sscanf` call.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I was not taking 7 characters but 6. In the first loop I removed the double-quotes and in the sscanf format I add an space after the comma. The problem is in the [^')'], because I am taking an extra white space. The solution is changing to [^' '].

Comment: `for(int i=2; i < strlen(incoming_message); i++)`  -- You shouldn't really call the `strlen` function on each loop iteration.  You don't even need `strlen`, as the string is a string-literal.  You know the length at compile-time.

Comment: @JonArrieta Why micromanage how much space you really need for the `char` array?  Just declare it more space than you expect, and you won't have this issue.  If you think you need exactly 6 or 7 characters, make the array 10 or 15.  Trying to get the size of the array correct, down to the right byte size, too many times results in situations such as yours.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You are right, I should leave some extra space for unexpected messages.

Comment: In  
`for(int i=2; (incoming_message[i]!='\r') || i < strlen(incoming_message); i++)`    
   
   
    
`(incoming_message[i]!='\r')`
    will be called before       
`i < strlen(incoming_message)`
This might be a problem in future.

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests, this error occurs when you write more characters than the allocated space. In this case, you are writing 7 characters to an array having space for 6 characters.

```
char network_number[6]; // This should be increased in size.
```

Comment: Actually 8. Don't forget the string terminator.